# onclick listner not firing in android popup

Tags: android

I have attached my code here, i have tried all ways but can't close the pop up window,please help, thanks in advance

```
for (int i = 0; i < chitlist.size(); i++) {
                        if (chitid.equalsIgnoreCase(chitlist.get(i).ChitNo)) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.monthlychitpopup, null);
                            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
                            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, true);
                            popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupWindowAnimation);

                            View pView = popupWindow.getContentView();


                            //some code here


                             close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.chitpopclose);
                            close.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                                }
                            });


                            popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Both onclick and setTouchInterceptor events not working.

Below is my full popup window layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#7F1404" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/laypop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chitpopclose"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
            android:text="Close"
            android:textColor="#5F0404" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chitpopchitid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edgepopup"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ChitId"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chitpopchitid"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edgepopup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Month Amt"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chitpopmnamt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Month Amt"
                android:textSize="16dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Installment"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chitpopinstallment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Installment"
                android:textSize="16dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rec.Amount"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chitpoptotamt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Re.Amount"
                android:textSize="16dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="110dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chit Date"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chitpopchitdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Chit Date"
                android:textSize="16dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/laypop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edgepopup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/main_color_gray_dk"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="S.No"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0.75dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_light" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0.75dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:background="@color/gray_light" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:text="Amount(Rs.)"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/popchitgriddetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try pView.removeAllViews();

Comment: using pView.removeAllViews(); is not a standard way to close the popup window, it may be a hack to do the same.

Comment: karthik-avk, Why are you initializing popupWindow second time?

Comment: Please also show your layout for monthlychitpopup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last line where you are initializing you popupwindow second time.

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Chaman Saini, but the close button not working,when i press back button twice the popup close

Comment: pressing back button twice is closing the popup because you are creating that popup two times.

Comment: i removed the last line, after that only this problem